# Using Drive API with Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am following Google Documentation to upload a file to Google Drive on windows with Java, but I have an error in the following line that I cannot figure out why I have it!
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

I have all the .jar files needed, the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method insert(File, FileContent) is undefined for the type Drive.Files
```

When I move the cursor close to insert, it says Add cast to service.files()

Can someone help me please? 
The code I have is exactly like the documentation (if scroll down the link I provided pls)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which version of the JARs do you actually have?  The Drive API has changed quite a bit over time.

Comment: google-api-services-drive-v3-rev11-java-1.21.0, the latest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `v2` Google Drive API code but you are including the `v3` JAR files.  If you really want to use `v3` then you will have to use the `v3` API.  Realize that `insert()` is apparently now called `create()`.  So you should replace your line of code with something along these lines:

```
File file = service.files().create(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

If you wish to use the `v2` API, then you will have to switch to the `v2` JARs.
 Here is what your POM might look like should you choose to use the `v2` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev206-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great, Thank you sir
Google needs to tell us API version on the page we are downloading the .jar files!

Comment: Yes, the documentation can be a bit confusing, and I have the feeling that changes to the API can come very quickly.